# how can i get the coordinates of an object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I get the coordinates of an object that is moving. I used `object.x += 10` to move the object when a key is pressed so how can I return the x coordinate of an object because I tried printing `object.x` and it doesn't return the right coordinate.

Comment: Normaly `object.x` do the job, but you said that it doesn't return the right coordinate so could you give us more details or show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trace(object.x);
```

returns the proper x coords of object.  If you need to see the coords in game for some reason they could be set to a variable and then set the variable to be refreshed as often as needed, then call the variable in a textfield.

Hope this helps!